# CPU trends in DB level report by script in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

CPU trends in DB level report by script in sql server 2014.

Any script for finding the DB level CPU usage report for couple of days.

Example:
We have 10 DB's in server and need to know about CPU usage for each and individual database by script.

Comment: Read Brent Ozars answer here.  This is something you can find pretty fast on Google and pick something that will work best for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952/cpu-utilization-by-database

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started. You can schedule a job to run this and capture over a period of time to report.

-- Get CPU utilization by database (CPU Usage by Database)
 -- Helps determine which database is using the most CPU resources on the instance

```
 WITH    DB_CPU_Stats
           AS ( SELECT   DatabaseID ,
                         DB_NAME(DatabaseID) AS [Database Name] ,
                         SUM(total_worker_time) AS [CPU_Time_Ms]
                FROM     sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
                         CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    CONVERT(INT, value) AS [DatabaseID]
                                       FROM      sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle)
                                       WHERE     attribute = N'dbid'
                                     ) AS F_DB
                GROUP BY DatabaseID
              )
     SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [CPU_Time_Ms] DESC ) AS [CPU Rank] ,
             [Database Name] ,
             [CPU_Time_Ms] AS [CPU Time (ms)] ,
             CAST([CPU_Time_Ms] * 1.0 / SUM([CPU_Time_Ms]) OVER ( ) * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5,
                                                               2)) AS [CPU Percent]
     FROM                                                      DB_CPU_Stats
     WHERE                                                     DatabaseID <> 32767
     ORDER BY                                                  [CPU Rank]
 OPTION  ( RECOMPILE );
```